# Babel creates output directory but doesn't transpile any files

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs, transpiler

I am trying to transpile a project that uses ES6 syntax and TypeScript. I have a directory structure like this:

```
├── .babelrc
├── src
    ├── index.ts
    └── pitching
        ├── pitching.test.ts
        └── pitching.ts
```

I would like to compile everything in `src` and output into `dist/`. I have tried many variations of the following command (specified in the `"build"` script in `package.json`):

```
babel ./src -d ./dist
```

But I always get the following output:

```
$ babel ./src -d ./dist
Successfully compiled 0 files with Babel (13ms).
Done in 0.32s
```

The result is an empty `dist/` directory in my project root. I tried compiling to a single file instead of a directory, which did create a compiled file, but all the module paths referenced in the code were messed up because they were relative to the `src` directory. I only mention this because to me it indicates that my babel setup is correct, though maybe I am wrong about that too.

My question is, why are my files not being transpiled, or how can I troubleshoot? The command doesn't give me any helpful output, even when I add the `{"debug": true}` to the presets in my `.babelrc`.

For reference, here are the babel packages and versions I am using:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.10.3",
    "@babel/core": "^7.10.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.10.3",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.10.1",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.3",
    "jest": "^26.1.0"
}
```

and here is my `.babelrc`

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-typescript"]
}
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try adding the proper file extensions. The reason for this is `babel/preset-typescript` needs an extra argument to transpile as expected. See documentation [here](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-typescript).

**React** applications compile both `ts` and `tsx` files.

```
babel --extensions .ts,.tsx ./src -d ./dist
```

Plain typescript applications just use `ts` files.

```
babel --extensions .ts ./src -d ./dist
```

Comment: Is there no way to configure this in `.babelrc` ?  I do have 
{
        "allExtensions": true,
        "isTSX": true
      }`
but still getting compiled 0 files

Comment: @SunnyPatel If you can get a minimal running version on something like stackblitz I'd be happy to take a peek

Answer (score 11):

In my case I was already using the `--extensions '.ts'` flag, but still getting "Successfully compiled 0 files". I'm not sure what else is different between our setups, but for me what solved it was the solution outlined [here](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/9803#issuecomment-505435797). Once I *removed* the wrapping quotes around the `.ts` it started working.